# Android toggle camera/video preview mode

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to change the preview mode of the camera(not for recording) on a surfaceView.

I saw it in the "Better Camera" [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.almalence.opencam&hl=en)

In this app, there is a button at the bottom of the app that toggles between "Image" and "Video" mode.

I tried to find a way to do so, but with no success. 
Maybe I don't look for the right keywords.

How can I implement it, please?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

This is a screenshot from the app, for what I want to implement:

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? No, I will not install the app to check

Comment: In the previous version of Android camera app, there was a toggle button that switches between Picture and Video mode.
The camera acting differently in preview (not recording) video and picture mode. I would like to know how can I switch between them?

Comment: I will update the question with screenshot from the app.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define a custom button in your layout XML that will switch between two modes?

Comment: The button is not the issue, the switching between still mode and video mode is my problem (Not in record time)

Comment: can you explain the difference in behavior? sorry still totally unclear how to help

Comment: For example, The White Balance is different, it takes more time to the Torch flashlight to stabilized.
BTW I have nothing to the app I've linked, I believe that there are more apps that doing so.